# Uploading to S3 bucket with KMS

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I am new with S3 and created myself a simple bucket, I let all the default settings as it.

I've ran [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html) and it works well..

Now my mission is to change the server side encryption to KMS. I've created new bucket using KMS as server side encryption. At the moment the policies of the KMS are admins so I waste time in permissions issues.

The same upload example works well in the bucket with the KMS as well - without changing the code.

I've tried in the beginning to add this line to the `PutObjectRequest`

```
PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(keyName)
                .serverSideEncryption(ServerSideEncryption.AWS_KMS)  // <<-------
                .contentType("text/plain")
                .build();
```

But it causes my upload to crash - forbidden 403.
If I don't use this line the upload is working.

So i've googled for the answer and found that if we add the header `"x-amz-server-side-encryption="aws:kms"` to the upload request it should work. and indeed it is.

My question is.. Why do we need it? S3 is anyway doing the encryption even if I don't set this line. Isn't it ?